# How can I reverse changes on my Xcode project? Stuck and nothing is working

Tags: ios, xcode

I created a simple iOS app. I wanted to test it on my own iPhone, and therefore attempted to create an ipa file. For that, I attempted to archive the project. It asked me for my keychain password, but when I put in the (correct) password, it didn't go through. So I closed the window by clicking "deny" for the keychain password. After this, the build failed and ever since then I can neither run the project, nor attempt to archive it again.

Nothing works and everything is stuck. I really don't want to lose my project and am in desperate need of help. I would like to reverse everything that I did until right before I attempted to archive. Can this project be saved or is it a lost cause?

Comment: This is why you use git even on local only projects

Comment: although at second glance you have probably just denied xcode keychain permissions

Comment: How can I undeny them?